# add class to angular2 directive like component does

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-directives, webpack-2, angular-components

Cause (this is angularTS project):
I want to just give some styles for my HTML element, say, `<input>`. If I wrap it into a component (`<my-input>`), then I'll also need to take care lots of other logic such as 2-way binding (lots of original support to `input` tag by angular will get lost). This makes it very hard to maintain and buggy.

So, I think of making an attribute directive to do that. Now I can just add one more attribute like `<input fancyStyle='floating'>` and use other angular stuff the old way such as ngModel or FormValidation.

Worked but not prefect way:
I'm able to use host or hostBinding or renderer to either add a bunch of single styles: `renderer.setElementStyle(el.nativeElement, 'color', this.fancyStyle);
renderer.setElementStyle(el.nativeElement, 'other1', this.fancyStyle);
renderer.setElementStyle(el.nativeElement, 'other2', this.fancyStyle);`
Very verbose..

REAL QUESTION GOES HERE----->
Or use `renderer.setElementClass()` or `host: {'[class.someclass]': 'true'}` to set a class, but the thing is I have to put this actual class to global style sheet or a specific component's style sheet, which is becoming a mess when I have more directives and very hard to maintain. Is there a way/hack to use it like component's way (associate a style file to this directive, and put them in same folder)? Or is there a way to wrap a component without affecting it's original usage?

Or is there a way to config webpack to do that? (noticed in Ionic project, I can add style to the file that isn't set styleUrls in component, but not sure how they config that).

Comment: What do you mean by "lots of original support to input tag by angular will get lost" .. that does not seem right at all. ng2 is component based, how would you lose "support"?

Comment: say, you made a component called 'MyInput', in it's template all you did just write `<input type='text'>`. So now, you're not able to use those angular supports made for `<input>`, for example, can't do this `<my-input [(ngModel)]='gg'></my-input>` while `<input [(ngModel)]='gg'>` is totally valid  and easy to use. The only way to make it valid is also to set an @input and @output and some tricks such as model/modelChange to deal with that. And there are more other supports that I don't use now but maybe in future, so if I wrap into a component, it will cause potential bug and hard to find.